# Iterating through an activerecord::relation array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I iterate through an array of Activerecord::Relation objects? For instance, let's say I have a `Comment` class and a `User` class and I'd like to get all the comment contents from 3 specific users (assuming comments belong to users and user_id is the foreign key):

```
>> @males = Comment.where('user_id IN (?)', ["123","456","789"])
=> [...] #Array of comment Activerecord::Relation objects
```

Now I'd like to iterate through `comments_from_males` and collect all the `content` attribute contents for each comment in the array.

To clarify, the following works but only for the first male returned, but I need all the comments for all males:

```
>> @males.first.comments.map(&:content)
=> ["first comment", "second comment"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
comments = @males.map {|user| user.comments.map(&:content)}.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
comments_from_males = @males.collect{|e| e.content if e.gender == "male"}.flatten
```

It will give you list of all comments from males. Check my db assumptions match.

Answer (score 1):

```
Comment.where('user_id IN (?)', ["123","456","789"]).pluck(:content)
```

The method [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Comment: Activerecord::relation objects don't have a pluck method available to them.

Comment: Example from documentation - Person.where(:confirmed => true).limit(5).pluck(:id)